# Multiple requests for a single computationally expensive resource in Go

Tags: go

Looking for a more Go-ish solution to the following:

Say, a server have multiple parallell incoming requests asking for a resource with key `key`. Since computing this resource is expensive/time consuming, we'd like to ensure that is is computed only once. There are infinitely number of possible keys.

One naíve implementation:

```
if hasCachedValue(key) {
   return cachedValue(key)
}
if somebodyElseWorkingOn(key) {
   waitUntilReady(key)
} else {
   buildCacheValue(key) // time consuming
}
return cachedValue(key)
```

So far we have solved this using a shared `map[string]chan bool`, where the first request inserts the chan for `key`, and the following requests waits for a close on that chan when the value is ready. To protect the map we use a `sync.Mutex`, but we have a feeling there is a better and more Go-ish solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a sync.Once?

Comment: There are infinitely number of keys. Not sure how sync.Once could fit :thinking_face:

Comment: Use the [singleflight](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [singleflight](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight) package. Declare a package-level variable for the group:

```
var g singleflight.Group
```

Use the following code to get the value:

```
v, err, _ := g.Do(key, func() (interface{}, error) {
    if !hasCachedValue(key) {
        buildCacheValue(key)
    }
    return cachedValue(key), nil
})
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
x := v.(valueType) // assert to type returned by cachedValue
// do something with x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that does what you want. I tested it and it works without problem. The Go race condition checker detects no problem.

```
type Cache struct {
    mtx sync.RWMutex
    m map[KeyType]*CacheValue
}

type CacheValue struct {
    val *ValueType
    mtx sync.Mutex
}

func NewCache() *Cache {
    return &Cache{m: make(map[KeyType]*CacheValue)}
}

func (c *Cache) Get(key KeyType) *ValueType {
    c.mtx.RLock()
    v := c.m[key]
    c.mtx.RUnlock()
    if v != nil {
        v.mtx.Lock()
        x := v.val
        v.mtx.Unlock()
        if x != nil {
            return x
        }
    }

    if v == nil {
        c.mtx.Lock()
        v = c.m[key]
        if v == nil {
            v = &CacheValue{}
            c.m[key] = v
        }
        c.mtx.Unlock()
    }

    v.mtx.Lock()
    if v.val == nil {
        v.val = buildValue(key)
    }
    v.mtx.Unlock()
    return v.val
}
```

Comment: @mh-cbon go routine trying to access the computed value wait, as specified by the OP. This doesn’t block any other access.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the Ping Pong example often used to describe channels, we sat out to try a channel-only approach. A ball keeps the state about keys being generated, and the ball is passed between the requests a shared channel:

```
import "time"

var table = make(chan map[string]chan bool)

func keeper() {
    for {
        ball := <- table
        table <- ball
    }
}

func getResource(key string) {
    // Take ball from table
    ball := <- table

    if wait, ok := ball[key]; ok{
        println("Somebody else working on " + key + ", waiting")
        table <- ball
        <- wait
    } else {
        println("I will build " + key)
        ball[key] = make(chan bool)

        // Throw away ball
        table <- ball

        // Building value
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
        println("I built value for " + key + "!")

        // Clean up ball
        ball = <- table
        close(ball[key])
        delete(ball, key)
        table <- ball
    }

    println("Now value for " + key + " has been built")
}

func main(){
    go keeper()

    ball := make(map[string]chan bool)
    table <- ball

    key := "key"
    go getResource(key)
    go getResource(key)
    go getResource(key)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```